# After Install Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I Install Magento 2, It works Fine but Under the `app/design/Frontend/Magento/` Getting Null. Unable to find Default Theme Structure. So Anyone can Help me what was the problem?
Any Kind of help Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

By Default **magento 2 have Luma Active Theme** and its parent theme name is magento blank theme.

To find the default theme strcture of Luma Theme follow this path : **YourmagentoDirectory/Vendor/Magento/theme-frontend-luma**

Same way for blank theme follow this path : **YourmagentoDirectory/Vendor/Magento/theme-frontend-blank**

> **app/design/Frontend/Magento** is used for overriding the theme or if you want to create your custom theme then you need to put your theme
>   files in this directory So by Default its **Null**.

Refer this link for create custom theme and theme structure details - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html

Comment: under this path `YourmagentoDirectory/Vendor/Magento/` I can not  find any folders like `theme-frontend-luma`  and `theme-frontend-blank` . so what was the problem

Comment: which version  you have installed ? also from where you have download m2 ?

Comment: Download From: `https://magento.com/tech-resources/download`  And Version : Magento ver. 2.0.2

Comment: This is the first version of magento 2 which include all core modules in /app/code/ folder but after that Magento released new version which has lots of changes, even in structure.

Magento 2.1 : all core modules moved to vendor directory. -

Answer (score 0):

Magento built-in themes can be located under `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-<theme_code>` when a Magento instance is deployed from the Composer repository.

Storefront themes are conventionally located under `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/` so if you want to override or create a new theme you can start from here.

Look Into [magento documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-structure.html) for more details